# Tables from Django packages

Tags: api, django-models, django-mysql, django-packages

How you’re doing, I’m using a package in Django for Instagram API, it creates a table in the admin page with a media Id, the link, the date, and the caption. But I can’t find this table on the project, how can I use this model on a view, and display the data it contains on a template. And I’m using MySQL.

Comment: Can you specify *what* package you are using?

Comment: I've resolved it guys, thank you.